# If $p, q, r$ are primes such that $p^2+q^2+r^2-222pqr=2017$ and $p\geq max(q,r)$, evaluate $(p+1)/{(q+1)(r+1)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I figured that since Odd-Even=Odd, $p^2+q^2+r^2$ has to be odd. I came up with $p^2\equiv1\pmod4, q^2\equiv1\pmod4, r^2\equiv1\pmod4$ but I cannot proceed further. What is the trick in finding the actual values of $p, q, r$?

Comment: I don't think there are any solutions. What's the source of this problem?

Comment: It is from my math prep book made by my old teacher. May I ask how it may not have a solution?

Comment: oh nm, there are solutions.

Answer (score 4):

(Fill in the gap as needed. If you're stuck, show your work.)

**Hint:** Work modulo 3.
Show that $ q = r  = 3$.
(I previously assumed that the primes were distinct.)

Hence show that $ p = -1, 1999$, of which we reject $-1$.